# Tree-like comments in django

Tags: django, comments

I'm trying to implement tree-like comments for my django projects. Each comment can be replied and is saved as given comment child.

```
comment 1
|- reply 1 to comment 1
|- reply 2 to comment 1
|- reply 3 to comment 1
   |- reply 1 to reply 3 to comment 1
   |- reply 2 to reply 3 to comment 1
comment 2
|- reply 1 to comment 2
... and so on ...
```

Here is my model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author              = models.ForeignKey(User)
    parent              = models.ForeignKey(Comment, blank=True) #
    text                = models.TextField()
    created             = models.DateTimeField()
    updated             = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

Is this the way to go, or am I reinventing the wheel? I'm sure that this is typical enough case so there are built in solutions for something like that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called threaded comments. It's not built in, but here's an app for that which you could

- a. use
- b. learn from to roll your own

https://github.com/ericflo/django-threadedcomments

Comment: An interesting article from disqus developer, when count of comments gets extreme: http://justcramer.com/2010/05/30/scaling-threaded-comments-on-django-at-disqus/

Comment: Looks that link no longer works, this appears to be what you were linking too? https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments